# Manually Setting a firebaseStorageDownloadTokens on image Upload to Firebase Storage with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to put a file to Firebase Storage with the following:

```
    final metadata = firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
    customMetadata: {'firebaseStorageDownloadTokens': customToken});

    _uploadTask =
    _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(widget.file!, metadata);
```

I get the following error in my console:

E/StorageException( 6906): Caused by: java.io.IOException: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Not allowed to set custom metadata for firebaseStorageDownloadTokens" }}

Submitting this as both a bug & feature request on the plugin site, but in the meantime, in the off-chance I'm just writing this wrong, as documentation on this isn't thorough, I thought I'd submit here to see if anybody has done it successfully from the client.

I'll be writing a cloud function later if I can't do it from client, but since this isn't a high security thing I'm doing...I have many reasons to avoid forcing my app to get the downloadUrl....my aim is to create a predictable downloadUrl...readily done in the cloud, I know, just looking to do it from the client here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to some folks, this is not allowed from the client. It has to be done with a Cloud Function.  It's highly discouraged. Here is why:

Anyone can access images if they have the image ID and the downloadToken. The idea is that both are hard to guess...hence an modicum of security. You can set security rules to getDownloadUrl for authenticated users, hence "restricting" the viewability through the obscurity of the image name, downloadToken and location.

By manually setting a downloadToken, you erode that "security."

It is allowed, however, you have to do it with a cloud function, triggering on create of the image, over-writing the auto-generated downloadToken.  Send me a DM for help in that if you need it.